# What is the best queue cache to use in concurrent environment in java

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, concurrency

I have a requirement to have a queue cache of messages in multi threaded environment where thousands of requests are coming per seconds.

Each request thread should pop out the message from queue (AND NO THREAD SHOULD GET DUPLICATE MESSAGE) if queue is not empty + decrements a counter in db .And if the queue is empty the thread will fetch a fixed number of message (for example 100) from DB and fill the queue cache (other thread should wait while the queue is filling) and then pop-out one message + decrements a counter in db and return.

The poping out and decrementing counter in db should be in synch to avoid any inconsistency.

So from the requirement it is clear that cache will have more read and remove (pop-out) operation however less write operation (only when the cache is empty).

Right now i have a synchronized method getMessage which has a ArrayList in it and I do the above operation (pop-out if empty else fetch and then pop-out) in  in this method but i have obviously facing a lot of contention issue.

If at read/remove time, concurrent threads get different locks and at the time of write, the lock should be on whole cache then this will reduce my contentions issue.

Which java cache should be best  in this case? In load i am facing low performance due to this. Kindly give me some better idea.

Comment: Most likely your poor performance is due to your database not your choice of cache. Just about any cache can handle 1000 operations per second.  If you read a message and your process fails before it can process it you will want to receive it more than once.

Comment: What behaviour do you expected if both caching queue and DB ones are empty ? As @PeterLawrey mentioned, you problem should be DB related. I think you're blocking your entire system while fetching/updating data from DB. Only use DB lock mechanisms for this feature but don't block the caching queue.

Comment: @ PeterLawrey as per the stats the db operation's average time is in milli however the getMessage average time is in seconds and it is increasing as the time grows.

Comment: @LoganMzz if the db and cache is empty the api will return empty response. yes the whole method is synchronizes and all cache and db operations are all inside it. What is DB lock mechanisms ?

Comment: In RDBMS, use "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" or a modification query ("INSERT", "UPDATE", "DELETE") to put a lock on keys, pages or tables (based on your locking settings). For other technologies, you may have to use other mechanisms. Which product are you using ?

Comment: @user2492242 Why don't use messaging broker (JMS, AMQP, etc.) with backing storage support (ie RabbitMQ, Kafka) instead of double queue ?

Comment: @LoganMzz I am using casssandra . I am not sure it has such locks.I cant use any other technology at this point due to management issue :) ..Need to fix it using java + cassandra

Comment: It takes seconds to remove a single element from an array list? Rather unbelievable except if you're locking way more than necessary out have a really large array and remove from the wrong end. In any case a concurrent blocking queue sounds like what you need. There are optimize ring buffer solutions, but those really shouldn't be necessary here

Comment: @user2492242 As you're using Apache Cassandra, why don't use Cassandra trigger, to turn your data store it into a message broker ? It's a common pattern. Push/Async/Message systems always scale better than Pull ones.

Comment: @Voo It is not just the time to remove form list . As i have sychronized whole method and hundreds of thread per second coming in, few thread might starve for longer time to acquire the lock and hence in stats  it increases the average time  . Also in the same method i am fetching messages form db if the cache is empty and updating the counter on each request. The concurrent blocking queue i don't find any method like addAll where i can put all the fetched message at once. I am looking at ReentrantReadWriteLock  now but never used this.

Comment: @user2492242 Sounds like your much, much bigger problem is the locking strategy. But the whole thing is confusing anyhow: So you load things into a queue (presumably so you only get the latency of the db access only once) but then the next thing you do is write to the db every time you access the queue - at which time the whole point of the queue is rather lost really.

Comment: 1. loading of queue is done on an average once in 3 seconds considering we fetch 1000 messages at once and 400 requests coming per seconds. 2. In the above scenario each 400 thread are doing poll + db update by aquiring the same lock (biggest problem) . What i want is that readers should get different locks and so that no one should wait lock to release however when loading happens i want that every thread to wait till the loading is complete . However while reading the shared message cache i have to make sure no duplicate message is read. In case db is empty empty response should return.

Comment: @user2492242 the point is you could avoid all of these problems by doing that logic on the database itself. Since every single item handling requires access of the db anyhow, avoid the cache and use the db for everything. On the other hand there probably are ways around needing to contact the database for every single handling - Not enough information.

Comment: 1. If both queue are empty and simply doing nothing, it means you enter in aggressive loop similar to `while (true);`. 2. Then only one thread should acquire message from DB at once. So all other ones have to starve (which whatever will cause latency problems). Except if you have a fragmentation mechanism that permit many reader w/o duplicate read. 3. You should consider to have clear separation between cache queue consuming and cache queue producer. 4. From queue consumer poll once, if fail then signal for DB queue consumer and take to block.

Comment: @LoganMzz thanks for your advice. In my case any request from client can become producer at the time when cache is empty and the same thread will consume one message . However requests from client become consumers if cache is not empty.

Comment: @Voo The cache implementations was intended to reduce the number of fetch query. If we don't implement cache then on every request one fetch and one update query will execute.

Comment: "getMessage average time is in seconds" something is really wrong.  You can get a message (pull not even push) over the internet from anywhere in the world in well under half a second.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Synchronize` you can look into `ReentrantLocks`. For your requirement there is an `ReentrantReadWriteLock` Class in Java. You can refer the Java docs for details. Basically an `ReentrantReadWriteLock` is recommended in cases where data is accessed by more reader threads than writer threads.

As per this implementation, multiple threads can read the same resource without locking. But a single write operation to the resource locks it and no other reads nor writes are allowed at the same time.

There are many sample examples available online which you can refer to implement `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Sample:

```
package concurrency.reentrantreadwrite;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class ReentrantReadWrite {
    public static ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
    public static StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer("a");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Reader(lock, message));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new WriterA(lock, message));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new WriterB(lock, message));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    }
}


package concurrency.reentrantreadwrite;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class Reader implements Runnable 
{
    ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = null;
    StringBuffer message = null;

    public Reader(ReentrantReadWriteLock lock, StringBuffer message) {
    this.lock = lock;
    this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
    for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i ++) 
    {
        if(lock.isWriteLocked()) {
        System.out.println("I'll take the lock from Write");
        }
        lock.readLock().lock();
        System.out.println("ReadThread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " ---> Message is " + message.toString() );
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
    }
}


package concurrency.reentrantreadwrite;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class WriterA implements Runnable 
{
    ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = null;
    StringBuffer message = null;

    public WriterA(ReentrantReadWriteLock lock, StringBuffer message) {
    this.lock = lock;
    this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
    for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i ++) 
    {
        try {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        message.append("a");
        }finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    }
}

package concurrency.reentrantreadwrite;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class WriterB implements Runnable 
{
    ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = null;
    StringBuffer message = null;

    public WriterB(ReentrantReadWriteLock lock, StringBuffer message) {
    this.lock = lock;
    this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
    for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i ++) 
    {
        try {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        message.append("b");
        }finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: as it allows multiple read simultaneously how it will meet (AND NO THREAD SHOULD GET DUPLICATE MESSAGE) requirement. Wont it  cause duplicates when we fetch the message from queue.

Comment: The mechanism mentioned is the substitute for 'Synchronized' keyword wherein the contention will be reduced for the read/write operation. For Queue you can refer to Queue Implementation in java concurrent package like LinkedBlockingQueue ,ArrayBlockingQueue ,PriorityBlockingQueue ,DelayQueue ,SynchronousQueue. Each have their own advantage and disadvantage, you can pick and choose as per your requirement. These queue implementation will not send duplicate even if 2 threads are requesting data at same time.
Ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

When you're facing an architecture problem, you should extract a "model" and abstract any external part/systems with interfaces. Thus, you can easily start by making those interfaces waiting a fixed time, then randomly, next with sampled durations and so forth.

It makes you clearer how your algorithm/system works and make very easy to refactor/adapt until the "model" is satisfactory. As your model become clearer, it also make you easier to insert monitoring and show what/where you have to monitor. I can add more complete explanation if necessary.

From your problem, you should add better separation between "cache consuming" and "cache producing". You also have to use non-blocking algorithm and smoother push to the "cache". Note that "non-blocking" doesn't mean that yours threads will never starves ; if there's nothing to process, they will necessary be sleepy. However, they shouldn't block each other.

## External systems

As mentionned on the summary, external systems must be abstracted and default value/spent time must be used. Thus you can use the same scenarii/model but changing the way of stubbing.

Storage abstraction:

```
interface Storage<T> {
  /**
   * Fetch next messages.
   * @param target    Target collection to collect data.
   * @param fetchSize Maximum record to fetch.
   * @param Actually fetch messsages.
   */
  int drainTo(Collection<T> target, int fetchSize);
  /**
   * Update message.
   */
  void update(T message);
}
```

For message processing we will abstract it to Java 8 SE `Consumer`.

## Model

Here is an implementation from what I have understood from your question and related comments:

```
class Model<T>  {
  private Storage<T>  storage;
  private int         fetchSize;
  private Consumer<T> processor;

  /**
   * while active:
   *    Try to poll a message from cache
   *    if none:
   *      Fetch from storage
   *      Put fetched messages to cache
   *    else:
   *      Process message
   *      Update storage according to processed message
   **/
  public void consume(BooleanSupplier active) {
    try {
      while (active.getAsBoolean()) {
        T message = cache.poll();
        if (message == null) {
          // Fetch new messages from storage
          List<T> newMessages = new ArrayList<>(fetchSize);
          synchronized (storage) {
            storage.drainTo(newMessages, fetchSize);
          }
          // Push new messages to cache
          for (T newMessage : newMessages) {
            cache.put(newMessage);
          }
        } else {
          processor.accept(message);
          storage.update(message);
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      if (!active.getAsBoolean()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Static analysis

- If there's nothing to fetch, all threads will eagerly try to fetch storage.
- When cache is empty, all threads (except the first one) are queued on acquiring storage access. Making them to cumulative wait after each other.
- Worst, as `cache.put(T)` is a blocking operation and all other consumer threads might been waiting for storage access a deadlock will occur.
- All threads are doing the same job whatever system state is. For example fetching storage when cache is empty. Use non-blocking algorithm to make only one fetching the database and the other ones waiting from cache.
- Cache transfer must be smoother pushing messages as long as they are fetch from database.
- More pushing to cache mustn't block. When cache is full, storage fetching must be aborted. Then, thread can return in "cache consumer" instead of starving on "blocked cache producer".
- Waiting for cache exhaustion for fetching messages from storage adds bad latency. Because while one thread is starting to fetch from storage, all other ones are starving and are eagerly fighting to grab the very first cached messages.

## Dynamic run

I have written a small system to take measure. I have used the following parameters:

- `storage.drainTo` is blocking for 33ms

  - fetch size of 100
  - fetch throughput at 3k/s
- `storage.update` is blocking for 5ms
- I run the code for 10 seconds and interrupt all consumer threads
- I used 4 threads for 4 processors (Intel Core i5-2500K @ 3.3GHz)

My observations:

- `storage.drainTo`

  - Called   (per thread): 18 ; 17 ; 18 ; 18 (total=71)
  - Duration (per thread): 1,161ms ; 2,228ms ; 1,159ms ; 1,157ms (total=5,706ms)
  - 7100 messages have been virtually fetch from storage
  - Target call for 17-18 times is 561-594ms
  - Starvation per thread is: min=563ms ; max=1,667ms ; average=841ms ; sum=3,363ms
  - Starvation represents 8.41% of execution time `3,363ms / (4 x 10s)`
  - Fetch represents 14.26% of execution time
- `storage.update`

  - Called   (per thread): 1,766 ; 1,530 ; 1,766 ; 1,766 (total=6,828)
  - Duration (per thread): 8,807ms ; 7,631ms ; 8,809ms ; 8,807ms (total=34,054ms)
  - Update represents 85.14% of execution time

99.4% of execution time is spent on storage management. There's no issue with Java queues.

## Improvement

Based on my analysis, I suggest this version:

```
class ImprovedModel<T>  {
  private Storage<T>  storage;
  private int         fetchSize;
  private Consumer<T> processor;
  private StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

  /**
   * while active:
   *    Try to poll a message from cache
   *    if none:
   *      if storage available:
   *        Transfer from storage to cache
   *      else:
   *        Take message from cache
   *    if message:
   *      Process message
   *      Update storage according to processed message
   **/
  public void consume(BooleanSupplier active) {
    try {
      while (active.getAsBoolean()) {
        T message = cache.poll();
        if (message == null) {
          // Check storage availability
          int stamp = lock.tryWriteLock();
          try {
            if (stamp != 0) {
              storage.drainTo(cache, fetchSize);
            } else {
              message = cache.take();
            }
          } finally {
            lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
          }
        }
        if (message != null) {
          processor.accept(message);
          storage.update(message);
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      if (!active.getAsBoolean()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

- Lock mechanism relies on `StampedLock`. You may try other implementations but due to low cache miss it might not have meaningful impact.
- When both queues are empty only one thread will aggressively loop on storage fetch. Others will just be paused. Don't consuming CPU at all.
- To be performant storage API must:

  - first fetch a small quantity to quickly deliver messages to waiting "cache consumer"
  - use `offer` method in order to terminate on failure (cache full). Thus, "cache producer" can quickly returns to "cache consumer" state to help others to consume messages.
- Based on message processing+update VS storge fetch throughput, it may be a good idea to set fetch size near to cache limit.
- Ideally, you might add monitoring+heuristic system to dynamically adapt fetch size and storage fetch triggering (instead of waiting for cache emptiness). Simpler you can just add a thread which will periodically checks for new messages, optionally waken up by a "cache consumer" in case of empty cache.

New observations:

- `storage.drainTo`

  - Called   (per thread): 5 ; 30 ; 29 ; 10 (total=74)
  - Duration (per thread): 164ms ; 990ms ; 957ms ; 330ms (total=2,441ms ; -57.21%)
  - 7400 (+4.23%) messages have been virtually fetch from storage
  - Fetch represents 6.10% of execution time
- `cache.take`

  - Called   (per thread): 69 ; 44 ; 45 ; 64 (total=222)
  - Duration (per thread): 106ms ; 199ms ; 199ms ; 348ms (total=852ms)
  - Take represents 2.13% of execution time
- `storage.update`

  - Called   (per thread): 1,947 ; 1,761 ; 1,768 ; 1,863 (total=7,339 ; +7,48%)
  - Duration (per thread): 9,698ms ; 8,778ms ; 8,813ms ; 9,286ms (total=36,574ms)
  - Update represents 91.44% of execution time

You may deduce `cache.take` starvation by comparing new `cache.poll`+`cache.take` and old `cache.poll` throughput.

## Appendix

- You can see my simple/poor monitoring I have used to measure and export results at A simple implementation which allows CSV exportation is available on [BasicMonitor.java](https://gist.github.com/loganmzz/3cb8cd5caebc9aaeb5d0). You may also take a look at your IDE profiler, [JRockit Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index-090630.html) or [JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) / [Java Simon](https://github.com/virgo47/javasimon)
- For multithreading support, I have used another small utility class: [Executor.java](https://gist.github.com/loganmzz/fb73b85efe2f74df457b).
- You may also take a look at [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helped.